# Query the Minimum Value per day within a month's worth of data

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two sets of pricing data (A and B). Set A consists of all of my pricing data per order over a month. Set B consists of all of my competitor's pricing data over the same month. I want to compare my competitor's lowest price to each of my prices per day.

Graphically, the data appears like this:

Date:-- Set A: -- Set B:
1---------25---------31
1---------54---------47
1---------23---------56
1---------12---------23
1---------76---------40
1---------42

I want pass only the lowest price to a case statement which evaluates which prices are better. I would like to process an entire month's worth of data all at one time, so in my example, Dates 1 thru 30(1) would be included and crunched all at once, and for each day, there would only be one value from set B included: the lowest price in the set.

Important notes: Set B does not have a datapoint for each point in Set A

Hopefully this makes sense. Thanks in advance for any help you may be able to render.

Comment: What does the schema (tables and columns) that you're working with look like?

Comment: @sleona1 - I'm not sure that I understand your graphic.  You have multiple rows with the same `DATE`.  Is there an additional `PRODUCT_ID` column in the data so that your sample represents prices for 6 different products on the same date?  Or did you have multiple prices for the same product on the same day?  If B does not have a price on the first day of the month, do you need to find the price from the end of the prior month?  What is the output that you want?  Do you want 6 rows with the `DATE` and `SET A` columns identical to the sample input with a value of `23` in every row for `SET B`?

Comment: Are they just prices, or do they belong to a product of some sort? If it's just prices, you will only have one lowest per day, right?

Comment: Sorry- let me try to add some clarification. I'm (obviously, right?) new to this so try to bear with me. I'm still looking at Frank's code.. its definitely a start.

Comment: @GolezTrol Each price is essentially stand alone for my purposes. All really care about doing is, if (for example), 23 is the lowest price my competitor has, finding how many times my price is higher or lower or ties with that price. I assume my competitor's price changes (i.e. will have a new minimum) each day, so I want to re-do that analysis each day for my pricing data.

Comment: But you need something to compare it by, right? You cannot say you are cheap, because you sell goldfish for $4, while your competitor sells koi carps for $300. Comparing prices only makes sense if they are prices for the same product or service.

Comment: @JustinCave I have multiple prices for the same product o the same day. Do not worry about prior month. My output (as mentioned above) is just a count of the number of times my price wins, loses and ties compared to my competitor. Your last sentence essentially sums up what i was trying to do; I know how I could appropriately tabulate the data if '23' (for example) was in each row for Set B, so i was trying to solve the question without reinventing the wheel.

Comment: @sleona1 - I'm still not sure that I understand what your desired output is.  B's minimum on date 1 is 23.  There is 1 price during the day where A is better, 1 where A is a tie, and 4 where A is higher.  Are you expecting 4 columns in your output (`DATE`, `BETTER_CNT`, `TIE_CNT`, `WORSE_CNT`)?  So you'd get a single row with `DATE`=1, `BETTER_CNT`=1, `TIE_CNT`=1, and `WORSE_CNT`=4?  Or do you want a single result for the date?  If so, what is that single result?

Comment: @JustinCave I have a column for Better, Worse and Tie and depending on the relationship, a flag shows up in the corresponding row. With that information, I want to calculate WLT %'s, etc.

Answer (score 1):

That's a strange example you have - do you really have prices ranging from 12 to 76 within a single day?

Anyway, left joining your (grouped) data with their (grouped) data should work (untested):

```
with 
  my_prices as (
    select price_date, min(price_value) min_price from my_prices group by price_date),
  their_prices as (
    select price_date, min(price_value) min_price from their_prices group by price_date)
select 
  mine.price_date,
  (case 
     when theirs.min_price is null then mine.min_price
     when theirs.min_price >= mine.min_price then mine.min_price
     else theirs.min_price
   end) min_price
from
  my_min_prices mine
left join their_prices theirs on mine.price_date = theirs.price_date
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not sure that I understand your requirements.  My best guess is that you want something like

```
SQL> ed
Wrote file afiedt.buf

  1  with your_data as (
  2     select 1 date_id, 25 price_a,31 price_b from dual
  3     union all
  4     select 1, 54, 47 from dual union all
  5     select 1, 23, 56 from dual union all
  6     select 1, 12, 23 from dual union all
  7     select 1, 76, 40 from dual union all
  8     select 1, 42, null from dual)
  9  select date_id,
 10         sum( case when price_a < min_price_b
 11                   then 1
 12                   else 0
 13                end) better,
 14         sum( case when price_a = min_price_b
 15                   then 1
 16                   else 0
 17                end) tie,
 18         sum( case when price_a > min_price_b
 19                   then 1
 20                   else 0
 21                end) worse
 22    from( select date_id,
 23                 price_a,
 24                 min(price_b) over (partition by date_id) min_price_b
 25            from your_data )
 26*  group by date_id
SQL> /

   DATE_ID     BETTER        TIE      WORSE
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1          1          1          4
```